# Regex Non-capturing group when using OR ( | )

Tags: javascript, regex

## What I have:

I made this regex `/(\["?.+"?(?:,"?.+"?)*\]|(?:"([^"]*)"))(?:\.includes\("?)([^"]*)(?:"?\))/g`

And I want to match `[123].includes("Oi")  ==  "asdasd" && "asdw".includes("w")`

But in the capturing groups, I want to get the array `[123]` or the string, but without the quotes `asdasd`.

I was looking on how to use non capturing groups and saw this `(?:<CONTEXT>(<WHAT_YOU_NEED_TO_GET>)<CONTEXT>)`, so I made my regex like so, but when I use OR ( | ), this doesn't work.

On the second match, the capturing groups I'm getting are:

```
0: ""asdw".includes("w")"
1: ""asdw""
2: "asdw"
3: "w"
```

But what I want to get is:

```
0: ""asdw".includes("w")"
1: "asdw"
2: "w"
```

Check [Here](https://regex101.com/r/n70Djp/2) to see the capturing groups better

Comment: Are you trying to use regexp to match javascript code? Since `.includes()` is an Array and String method. If so, care to explain the use case?

Comment: I have a string with text, `.includes()` is a text, not the function. The problem is only in the regex to get the correct capturing group, check [here](https://regex101.com/r/n70Djp/2/)

Comment: I understand that. My question is about why you have a string containing that text to begin with. Are you writing a JS parser? I'm asking, since if you're not writing a parser or some other tool that manipulates JS code, there's probably better ways to solve the issue than regexp.

Comment: If you are trying to pull some matches from arbitrary JS code, you really should check existing JS parsers.

Comment: I don't want better ways to solve the issue, just want help with my regex. And the issue i'm having is with the regex, not with parsing js.

Comment: Why the down vote?? Isn't here the right place to ask questions about my code that I can't figure out how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Adding these as an answer.

Problem lies in first capturing group. The inner non-capturing one just tells the engine not to generate a capture, but it is already captured by the outer group.

Replacing `(\["?.+"?(?:,"?.+"?)*\]|(?:"([^"]*)"))` by `(?:\"([^"]*)\"|(\[[^\]]*\]))` should get the job done.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GH4RM6/2/).

Comment: And replacing the part you said, doesn't solve the problem, it still creates 3 groups, where the second group is undefined

Comment: Just edited for javascript. Still searching for only 2 groups, but I have no obvious solution for it yet. How do you exploit the results in your code?

Comment: the reason why I want only 2 groups is because when I destruct the array, I don't need to use commas with nothing inside e.g `let [match, , field, , atribute] = exec`

Comment: If I use only one OR ( | ), i only need to have one comma, but if I have more, I will need much more and the code will be harder to understand to me and others programmers

Comment: Would something like [`(\")?([^.\s]*)\1(?:\.includes\("?)([^"]*)(?:"?\))`](https://regex101.com/r/NGjOls/1/) suit your needs? I know there's still a meaningless group, but field will remain in the same one.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have no meaningless groups

Comment: Sorry then, that was the better I could think of using regex only.